# Webpack 5 config didn't generate html and bundle.js files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I started using webpack(v5) with React(v18), and I really struggle with how to configure the webpack file to auto-generate the dist folder that contains my HTML and JS files, I appreciate your help:

My webpack configuration, package.json, and index.js files are as follows:

Webpack file:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    static: "./dist",
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8563,
    open: true,
  },
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          "file-loader",
          {
            loader: "image-webpack-loader",
            options: {
              bypassOnDebug: true, // webpack@1.x
              disable: true, // webpack@2.x and newer
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      inject: 'body'
    }),
  ],
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
};
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development --config config/webpack.config.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.7",
    "@zarconontol/enzyme-adapter-react-18": "^0.7.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.1.1",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which command did you run to generate assets?

Comment: @tmhao2005 npm run start

Answer (score 1):

Since you run the `webpack` dev server with `start` command which means it will likely compile and serve the assets on memory rather than local disk, I think this is the [reason](https://webpack.js.org/guides/build-performance/#compile-in-memory). Hence in order to generate the assets on local disk you need to run `webpack` cli without `serve` option, let's create a `build` command such as:

```js
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
     // ...
     "build": "webpack"
  }
}
```

For the html template, ***you don't necessarily include the script file*** in there, `webpack` plugin takes care of it for you. Hence the only thing you need to do is to specify the `div#root` for your React app to init:

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, yes I think you're right now use this command to generate dist folder: ""start": "webpack --mode development --config config/webpack.config.js"

Comment: But I have another issues :
First: my file js is on head tag like that:
<script defer src="bundle.js"></script>
Second: I have this error:
 Error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

Comment: You might fix it by injecting the scripts inside the body by configure `HTMLWebpackPlugin({..., inject: 'body'})`

Comment: yes I already tried it: 
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
  ]

Comment: Did you add the option `inject: “body”`?

Comment: do you mean like that: new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      inject: 'body'
    }), ??
Now my bundle.js file is in the body, BUT I didn't get div#root in HTML file, and there is error: Uncaught Error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
which occurs because of missing of root id

Comment: You need to add the div with root id inside your template. Anyway how does it look like so far?

Comment: Do you mean I should manually in my HTML, or in "new HtmlWebpackPlugin({})" in webpack?? it doesn't render anything on browser

Comment: Yes we should put the root div element inside the template manually. Let share the index.html file if you don’t know what to do

Comment: OK,i will update the 3 files in my question above, just a minute please. Just I need to let you know that's I tried to add div#root in the HTML generated but I seems that it doesn't recognize React at all.

Comment: I edited the answer with the suggestion on updated template. Keep in my, pls remove your script tag

Comment: All what I got is blank page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248460/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-moez-ben-rebah).